# Drupal-7 An AJAX HTTP error occurred: HTTP result code: 200

Tags: jquery, ajax, drupal-7

I am running a very simple program on a new clean drupal installation. However, I am getting a small popup on the browser saying:

> An AJAX HTTP error occurred

I have not installed much modules except views, ctools modules on top of basic Drupal installation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it happen through this little information. But you can prevent it using a module [Prevent JS alerts](https://drupal.org/project/prevent_js_alerts).

This module completely suppresses ALL JavaScript alerts and instead prints them to console via console.error!
Important: It does NOT ONLY suppress the core alerts, but also custom alerts.

For more info go through module documentation.